# what is the best practice to reload AngularJS page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to know what is best practice to work with Auth Service and authInterceptor Service

```js
 $window.location.reload();
 $scope.$apply();
 $location.path('/');
```

Comment: AngularJS is mostly used for Single Page Applications (SPA). You **don't refresh**, you simply render new content

Comment: If you want to reload the page you don't need angularjs. Use pure javascript function: **location.reload()**

Comment: Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this in my application to rerender the data.if you are in the same state as well you will be able to rerender the data. `$state.transitionTo('app.emp.nav.portfolio', null, {'reload':true});`

Answer (score -1):

Using `$location.path('/')` in some cases could be useless because AngularJS won't refresh the controller if location doesn't change.

You should try to use this statement to re-render the page

```
$route.reload();
```

Remember to inject `$route` in your controller.

Also you can see AngularJS documentation about this: [AngularJS: API: $route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: This answer only applies if the app is using the ngRoute module. It does not apply if app uses the UI-router. There is no indication in the question that the OP is using any router.

Comment: When you have sufficient privileges, you will be able to add comments to get clarifications. For now limit your answers to ones that don't require clarification from the author.